# Get value from xml file www.bnr.ro java

Tags: java, web-services, web, url

The code show this error

> SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

when trying to read from this [xml file](http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml).

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml").openStream());
if(doc!=null){
    System.out.print("Not null");
} else {
    System.out.print("Null");
}
```